# How to access variable in the nested list and plot histogram

Tags: list, nested

I have data below:

```
[{'_id': {'day': 11, 'month': 10, 'site_id': '3146102', 'year': 2015}, 'totalVolume': 15731.74},

{'_id': {'day': 1, 'month': 10, 'site_id': '3146102', 'year': 2018},
  'totalVolume': 70537522.867},

{'_id': {'day': 30, 'month': 9, 'site_id': '3146102', 'year': 2018},
  'totalVolume': 293037881.211}]
```

How to access `month` and plot total volume based on `month`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help( pseudo code):

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [] # your data
data.sort(key=lambda k: k['month'])
data_to_plot = []

for month, month_data in groupby(data, lambda x: x['month']):
      month_total_production = sum(data['totalVolume'] for data in month_data)
      data_to_plot.append(tuple(month, month_total_production))

plot(data_to_plot)
```

Comment: @Yeni great, you can accept this as answer by clicking the tick button

Comment: @Yeni, keep you data sorted by month before grouping it, I have edited my answer accordingly

Comment: I got the result like this: 
[[7, <function __main__.<lambda>>],
 [9, <function __main__.<lambda>>],
 [10, <function __main__.<lambda>>]]
how to print month total production?

Comment: @Yeni great it helped finally, so you can finally click on green tick to accept the answer